# Android Studio: cambiar valor TextView por el de EditText al pulsar botón

Tags: android

Me interesa que el usuario escriba un texto en un edittext, y una vez pulsado un botón este texto escrito por el usuario se ponga en un TextView que hay creado. ¿Es esto posible? He probado con varios códigos y siempre me acaba crasheando al apretar el botón, ahora mismo tengo esto:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edittext;
    TextView textNomCognoms;
    ImageButton botoCancelar;
    ImageButton botoAcceptar;
    ImageButton botoEditar;
    ImageButton botoCancelar2;
    ImageButton botoTelefon;
    ImageButton botoVeureWeb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        botoCancelar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoCancelar);
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_nomcognoms);
        botoEditar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoEditar);
        botoCancelar2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoCancelar2);
        botoTelefon = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoTelefon);
        botoVeureWeb = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoVeureWeb);


        botoCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                edittext.getText().clear();
            }
        });

        botoAcceptar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoAcceptar);
        botoAcceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(edittext.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Escribe algo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    textNomCognoms.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Un saludo y gracias.

EDITADO: al final he podido solventarlo! Me faltaba el siguiente código:

```
textNomCognoms = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NomCognoms);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el tu código?

Comment: Hola MarcusF. bienvenido al sitio!, es importante realices el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te 
da información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida 
en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Comment: Agrega que error obtienes al pulsar el botón. Siempre agrega el mensaje desplegado en LogCat.

Comment: Perdonad! Código completo añadido. Tal cual está ahora si está la linea del final (lo de dentro del else) la app crashea al darle al botón.

Answer (score 1):

tienes que hacer lo siguiente :
1. dentro componente Button 
       
2. Instancias EditText y TextView en el metodo onCreate() de la clase java referente a tu actividad
3. Crear método con el nombre miEvento fuera del onCreate
4. dentro dek metodo miEvento coloca miInstanciaTextView.setTex = miInstanciaEditText.gettext().tostring();

Answer (score -1):

Debes asignar un `OnClickListener` a tu botón, dentro agregar la acción, en este caso lo que ya tienes realizado:

```
  //Busca instancia de Boton.
   botoAcceptar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botoAcceptar);
  //Define  OnClickListener  a instancia de boton.
  botoAcceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Agrega texto almacenado en EdtitText a TextView.
            textoView.setText(edittext.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```

---

**Actualización:**

El problema en realidad es que estas definiendo :

```
private TextView textNomCognoms;
```

pero no estas buscando la referencia de este TextView dentro de `activity_main.xml`

```
 textNomCognoms = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.???);
```

por esa razón obtienes un `NullPointerException` :

```
textNomCognoms.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Juraría que lo tengo igual y me crashea :S

Comment: Ok esto es como obtener la referencia del botón pero puede ser que esos elementos (Boton, TextView, EditText) no se encuentren dentro de activity_main.xml, agregalo por favor.

Comment: Hey porque -1 ? @MarcusF

Comment: Yo te he dado +1, ni idea de donde viene.